# Upgrade cakephp 2 app -> cakephp 3 app, `Cannot declare App because the name is already in use`

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, php-7

I am having a problem when attempting to upgrade my cakephp 2 app to cakephp 3.

I am using PHP 7.1 & Ubuntu 16 and nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

I am getting the following error...

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class lib\Cake\Core\App because the name is already in use in /usr/share/nginx/html/web/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 70
```

I am following this page: https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade

I am first using these commands:

```
bin/cake upgrade locations [path]
bin/cake upgrade namespaces [path]
bin/cake upgrade app_uses [path]

bin/cake upgrade rename_classes [path]
bin/cake upgrade rename_collections [path]
bin/cake upgrade method_names [path]
bin/cake upgrade method_signatures [path]
bin/cake upgrade fixtures [path]
bin/cake upgrade tests [path]
bin/cake upgrade i18n [path]
bin/cake upgrade skeleton [path]
bin/cake upgrade prefixed_templates [path]
```

Some more details:

My php version is (output of `php -v`) is:

```
PHP 7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

and my ubuntu version (output of `lsb_release -a`) is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Facing the same issue now ... Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have CakePHP on an include_path or have otherwise installed the upgrade plugin in a way that isn't `composer install` inside the upgrade plugin. Unless you've cloned the upgrade tool into `/usr/share/nginx/html/web/`.

Comment: the upgrade plugin is inside of /usr/share/nginx/html/upgrade and I have composer.phar installed in /bin, and I used that to install the upgrade tool, from inside /usr/share/nginx/html/upgrade, I ran all the

     `bin/cake upgrade [fill in the blank] ../web`

commands

Comment: I do have a backup of the old cakephp 2 version of my app

Comment: Well I used get_include_path to find my php include path, and found it in /usr/share/path, and then did ls there and found this:

7.0  7.1  Archive  Cake  Console  data  docs  OS  PEAR  pearcmd.php  PEAR.php  peclcmd.php  PHP  Structures  System.php  XML

running `sudo find -name Cake` from that folder gave me this:

./Cake
./data/CakePHP/Cake

Comment: I removed those two Cake directories from /usr/share/php (I backed them up) and restarted php7.1-fpm and nginx, and refreshed my server, and I'm still getting the same error.